# How to schedule process in the way that it should run immediately for the first time and run with scheduled time from second time in node js

Tags: node.js

I tried with node-schedule package
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule][1]

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

But if I schedule for 10 minutes and start the process it is processing after 10 minutes. 
In my case, I need the process to be run for the first time and later it should run with scheduled time.

Is there any solution for this kind of issue?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: What you did till now? Show your code.

Comment: Have you tried just running the 'process' first before scheduling it?

Comment: I have updated the code please check @timiTao

Comment: yes I tried it works but the issue I need is the explained thing in the question @KhauriMcClain

Comment: I am new to nodejs , not sure if it can be done, i would be tempted to know if it is possible. i usually test it before i schedule it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it , just found it

```
 let startTime = new Date(Date.now()) ;
 var j = schedule.scheduleJob({ start: startTime, rule:'42 * * * *'}, 
         function(){
         console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
       });
```

Hope this helps
See this documentation of [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#set-starttime-and-endtime/%22node%20schedule%22)

Comment: Firstly, sorry for the delayed reply. I have tried this but there is no use :| It is starting according to the rule mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use codes from https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron.

Then you can fire the crontab job at the second when you start nodejs program. After the crontab job will be run at certain interval.

This is an example to run the job immediately when creating the crontab work.

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
const job = new CronJob({
  cronTime: '0 */5 * * * *',
  onTick: () => console.log(`Round at ${new Date()}`);
  runOnInit: true
});

job.start();
```

In codes above, the "console.log" will be run when I start my program. Then it will run at every 5 minutes. For more usage, you can refer to the lib provided.